# Call SQL FUNCTION with parameters in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a question. I would call a SQL function through PHP language.

EX. "`SELECT * FROM dbo.openday_detail(eventID)`"

I was trying this:

```
        $eventID= 10000;

        $params="@eventID int";
        $paramslist="@eventID='$eventID'";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.openday_detail(eventID = @eventID)";
        $dbsql = "EXEC sp_executesql 
            N'$sql', 
                N'$params',
                $paramslist";

        $result=mssql_query($dbsql,$link);
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Statement would be "SELECT * FROM openday_detail WHERE eventID = :eventID"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pas an assignment inside the call to the procedure... try removing `eventID =` and be sure your @eventID is correctly initialized

Answer (score 0):

I tried  to insert directly the INT value, but it doesn't work...

I guess that the problem is the Table-Function...andI can't to access to DB to see/modify the function .

a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct statement would be :

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.openday_detail(@eventID)";
```

or

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.openday_detail("+ $eventID+")";
```

Comment: @Morris Can you please post your procedure code? So I can answer it accordingly.